# Consider the set F = {f : R → R} under composition. Is the subset L of linear L = {f ∈ F | ∃ a, b ∈ R s.t. f(x) = ax + b} closed under composition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the set F = {f : R → R} under composition. Is the subset L of linear functions  L = {f ∈ F | ∃ a, b ∈ R s.t. f(x) = ax + b}  closed under composition?

As far as I see it for any x∈R ∃a,b∈R f(x)∈R. Therefore is should be closed under composition. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If $g(x) = a x + b$ and $h(x) = c x + d$, what are $h(g(x))$ and $g(h
(x))$ equal to?

Comment: Your statement "for any $x \in \mathbb{R} \ \exists a,b \in \mathbb{R}\  f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$" doesn't make much sense... The real question is, if $f \in L$ and $g \in L$, is $g \circ f \in L$? That is, if $f$ is of the form $f(x)=ax+b$ and $g$ is of the form $g(x)=cx+d$, is $g\circ f$ of the form $(g\circ f)(x)=ex+h$?

Comment: h(g(x))=a(cx+d)+b=acx+ad+b, g(h(x))=c(ax+b)+d=cax+cb+d

therefore h(g(x)) is not equal to g(h(x))

correct?

Comment: They do not need to be equal to each other.  All you need to show is that a composition of linear functions is a linear function - which you have shown.

Comment: which proves that its closed under composition?

Comment: You have a subgroup essentially because if you substitute a linear function by a linear function you obtain again a linear function. You don't have this property with quadratic functions. If you don't care the degree the property is also shared by polynomials and strangely enough also by functions of the form $f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$.

Comment: If a set is "closed" under some operation, it means that if you apply that operation to two elements in the set, you will get another element in the set. In this example, $F$ is closed under composition, because if you compose $h(x)=cx+d$ and $g(x)=ax+b$, you have $$(h\circ g)(x)=c(ax+b)+d=(ca)x+(cb+d).$$ $h\circ g$ is linear with $x$-coefficient $ca$ and constant term $cb+d$. Thus, since the composition of two linear functions is linear, $F$ is closed. You do not need to show that $h\circ g=g\circ h$; if this were true, it would mean that composition is *commutative* in $F$, which it isn't.